# Как найти значения float, при этом не учитывая значения NaN

Tags: python, pandas, excel, float

Получил df из файла excel, нужно проверить, что бы в нем **не было значений float и str**. Могут быть значения **только nan и int**.
Но пустые ячейки в нем имеют <class 'float'>. Таким образом вот эта проверка не срабатывает:

```
    datatypes = df
    for y in datatypes:
       if datatypes[y].dtype == np.float64:
          print('try')
       else:
          print('false')
```

Она реагирует на nan и значения float, но nan допустимо!
Если так то только пустые значения:

```
data = df
    for y in data:
        if data[y].isnull().sum():
            print('try')
        else:
            print('false')
```

Еще раз вопрос, как мне задать условие что бы **найти значения float и str**, но **исключить nan и int** ?

Вот df для примера

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3.3, 4.4],'col3': [np.NaN, np.NaN]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Comment: тип данных nan  - это float, между прочим.

Comment: @strawdog спасибо, а как вопрос то решить?

Comment: Приведите к типу str, и сравнивайте. if datatypes[y].dtype == np.float64: вложенная проверка if str(datatypes[y].dtype) == 'nan': действие else: print("Это float")

Comment: приведите небольшой пример данных и желаемый результат

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str` определить просто - это `dtype == 'object'`, а для отличения `int` от `float` можно заполнить `NA` нулями, а после этого проверить, что при преобразовании столбца в `int` значения остаются такими же или нет. Пример:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'data1': [1, np.NaN, 2.2, 2, np.NaN], 
    'data2': [1, 2, np.NaN, 4, 5], 
    'data3': ['1', 2, 3, '4', np.NaN]
    })
for column in df.columns:
    data = df[column].fillna(0)
    print(column, end=': ')
    if df[column].dtype == 'object':
        print('str')
    elif (data.astype(int) == data).all():
        print('int')
    else:
        print('float')
```

Вывод:

```
data1: float
data2: int
data3: str
```

Я проверяю целиком столбцы но если нужно точно так же можно проверять и отдельные ячейки, наверное.

При этом никак невозможно отличить ситуацию, когда в столбце изначально были `float` числа без дробной части. Столбец из одних `int` при появлении в нём `NA` превращается в тип `float` и такую ситуацию никак нельзя отличить от той, когда в столбце изначально были `float` без дробной части. С точки зрения `Pandas` такие столбцы абсолютно одинаковы, мой метод даст оценку, что это был столбец типа `int`.

Comment: работает спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться [относительно новым типом данных Int64](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html#) (обратите внимание на **заглавную** первую букву):

```
In [72]: for col in df:
    ...:     try:
    ...:         df[col] = df[col].astype("Int64")
    ...:     except TypeError:
    ...:         pass
    ...:

In [73]: df.dtypes
Out[73]:
data1    float64
data2      Int64
data3     object
dtype: object
```

Таким образом мы можем преобразовать столбцы, в которых встречаются только целые значения и `NaN` в тип данных `"Int64"`.

PS в качестве примера данных я использовал пример данных из ответа уважаемого CrazyElf.